# How do anonymous functions work with routing's request and response objects passed as parameters

Tags: php, routes

I have come across a number if not a few of routing systems and/or frameworks that make use of anonymous functions in their routing systems - Laravel, Silex and Klein to name a few. Below is the obvious syntax am wanting an explanation on:

```
$requestHandler->run(function($request,  $response) use ($requestHandler){
  if($request->isAllowed()){
    $resource = new Resource($request->getPost());

    $response->prepare($resource);
  }

  if($response->hasErrors())
    \Log\ErrorLog::write($response->getErrors());

  return $response->getOutput();
});
```

The idea is to handle all my CURL requests like this but am not sure of how this concept works. Should I create instances of $request, $response and $requestHandler classes before I can use them as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make use of anonymous functions as outlined in my question above. I have simple created my dispatcher class as below:

```
namespace FileServer;

class Dispatcher
{

  public static function run($execution)
  {
    return $execution();
  }
}
```

In my index file I just run the code below:

```
\FileServer\Dispatcher::run(function(){

   echo "Hello anonymous funtion.";
 });
```

This works both via command-line and browser which means I am on the right direction. However, I am still confused with regards to where and how the parameters passed work because from the existing frameworks they just pass $request and $response as parameters but they are not instantiated anywhere.

If someone could enlighten me on how this works because the [php maual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) I followed isn't as clear for me.